# Пересчет координат при повороте изображения

Tags: c++

На изображении `1200x600` имеем отмеченную точку, например `125x345`.

Как ее правильно перещетать при повороте изображения на `90, 180, 270 градусов`?

Начал с этого, но верный результат отсутствует.

```
double angle = 270; int x = 125; int y = 345;

int xx = x * std::cos(angle) - y * std::sin(angle); 
int yy = y * std::cos(angle) + x * std::sin(angle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, вы должны определиться с якорной точкой - это точка через которую проходит ось вращения картины. К примеру вы можете вращать картинку относительно центра, относительно левого нижнего и правого верхнего углов.

Если у вас задача это поставить взаимно однозначное соответствие между точками, то начинать нужно с математики (логики), а не с программирования.

Во, вторых, когда я кодил на Си++, координаты отсчитвыались сверху (а не так, как в школе). Хотя в Си++ есть разные фрэймворки, от желания разработчика выбирается начало отсчёта координат.

Вот на картинке простой пример, когда ваша формула становится не корректной - я провращал изображение относительно левого нижнего угла. А нулевую координату взял в левом верхнем углу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваша исходная точка (125,345) при повороте на -90 градусов (те же 270 градусов) покажут, что новая координата будет иметь координату  (255, 125) если мы переместим точку D в начало координат.

Answer (score 4):

Формулы правильные, если имеется в виду вращение вокруг угла с координатами 0,0, а вот аргумент тригонометрических функций должен быть в радианах, а не в градусах

```
rad_angle = deg_angle * M_PI / 180
```

Кроме того, если углы нужны только `90, 180, 270 градусов`, то всё упростится, т.к. значения косинуса и синуса для этих значений будут 0, +1, -1, например

```
x90 = -y
y90 = x
```