# Как убрать точки (пробелы) при повороте изображения (матрицы)?

Tags: c++, изображения, матрицы

Брал формулу отсюда: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матрица_поворота](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)
Пытаюсь повернуть картинку, но получаю белые точки, со знаками игрался, но это не помогает. Тут: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063702/Пересчет-координат-при-повороте-изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063702/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) прочитал про отсчёт координат, я не учёл, что отсчёт с верхнего-левого угла. Возможно дело в округлении, но манипуляции с ним не дали результата. Что нужно изменить?

```
int* Plane1 = new int[256 * 100 * 3];
int Angle = 20;

int main()
{
    readBMPTo1dArray("Helicopter.bmp", Plane1, 256, 100);

    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        Angle = Angle + 1;
        if (Angle >= 360)
        {
            Angle = 0;
        }
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
            {
                red = (Plane1[y * 256 * 3 + x * 3 + 0] + 256) % 256;
                green = (Plane1[y * 256 * 3 + x * 3 + 1] + 256) % 256;
                blue = (Plane1[y * 256 * 3 + x * 3 + 2] + 256) % 256;

                COLORREF color = RGB(red, green, blue);

                int x1 = x * cos(Angle * M_PI / 180) - y * sin(Angle * M_PI / 180);
                int y1 = x * sin(Angle * M_PI / 180) + y * cos(Angle * M_PI / 180);

                SetPixel(hdc, x1 + 500, y1 + 500, color);
            }
        }
        Sleep(1000);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обратное преобразование, т.е. для каждой точки результата (r) ищите соответствующую точку исходного изображения (s).
Псевдокод при вращении вокруг центров :

```
for xr, yr:
   xs = cxs + (xr - cxr)*cos + (yr - cyr)*sin
   ys = cyr - (xr - cxr)*sin + (yr - cyr)*cos
   Result[xr, yr] = Source[xs, ys]
```

Comment: Я получил некоторый результат - без пропусков. К каким координатам исходного изображения происходит обращение вычисляется по формуле, но как узнать размеры циклов for? Как узнать координаты пикселя результирующего изображения, чтобы не прогружать весь экран 1000 * 1000?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462800/get-bounds-of-rotated-rectangle/51463527#51463527 две первые формулы